# Concatenating the records into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am stuck with performing a requirement in my report.

```
Name  Item_segment          Due_Date  Order_type    Total_Qty    Supplier name 

A          xx            11/18/2017        ABC         10          ababbcc

A          xx            11/18/2017        ABC         10         deffgg

B          xx            11/26/2017        ABC         40         xxyyzzz

C          xx            11/18/2017        ABC         10         deffgg

C          xx            11/30/2017        ABC         10          deffgg

C          xx            11/30/2017        DEF         10         deffgg

C          xx            11/30/2017        PQR         10         deffgg
```

Result set

```
Name  Item_segment          Due_Date  Order_type  Total_Qty      Supplier name 

A          xx            11/18/2017        ABC         10       ababbcc,deffgg

B          xx            11/26/2017        ABC         40         xxyyzzz

C          xx            11/18/2017        ABC         10         deffgg

C          xx            11/30/2017        ABC         10         deffgg

C          xx            11/30/2017        DEF         10         -----

C          xx            11/30/2017        PQR         10         -----
```

1.The supplier names should be reported with the orders having order type as 'ABC' and should be blank for others.

2.If 2 records are having different supplier names for the same combination of name,item_segment,due_date,order-type etc..then it should be combined into 1 row with ',' between them.

Answer (score 1):

You could use of `stuff()` function with help of `case` expression

```
SELECT Name, Item_segment, Due_Date, Order_type, Total_Qty,
       [Supplier name] = CASE(Order_type) WHEN 'ABC'
                             THEN STUFF((
                                          SELECT DISTINCT ','+[Supplier name] FROM <table>
                                          WHERE Name = t.Name FOR XML PATH('')
                                       ), 1, 1, '')
                             ELSE ' ' END
FROM <table> t
GROUP BY Name, Item_segment, Due_Date, Order_type, Total_Qty;
```

Result :

```
Name    Item_segment    Due_Date    Order_type  Total_Qty   Supplier name
A       xx              11/18/2017  ABC         10          ababbcc,deffgg
B       xx              11/26/2017  ABC         40          xxyyzzz
C       xx              11/18/2017  ABC         10          deffgg 
C       xx              11/30/2017  ABC         10          deffgg 
C       xx              11/30/2017  DEF         10   
C       xx              11/30/2017  PQR         10
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is ABC.

Try this:

```
Select Main.Name, Main.Item_segment,Main.Due_Date,Main.Order_type,Main.Total_Qty,
       Left(Main.Supplier_name,Len(Main.Supplier_name)-1) As "Supplier_name"
From
    (
        Select distinct ST2.Name, ST2.Item_segment, ST2.Due_Date, ST2.Order_type, ST2.Total_Qty,
            (
                Select ST1.Supplier_name + ',' AS [text()]
                From abc ST1
                Where ST1.Name = ST2.Name
                  and ST1.Item_segment = ST2.item_Segment
                  and ST1.Due_Date = ST2.Due_Date
                  and ST1.Order_type = ST2.Order_Type
                ORDER BY ST1.Name
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) as Supplier_name
        From abc ST2
    ) [Main]
```

Comment: Thank you so much..It helped me :)

Comment: Glad it helped. You can "mark as answer" and "up vote" if helpful. This way other users will also get benefited. [How to mark as answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)